# Read same lines in different context few lines after a match in python

Tags: python

I have file

```
Header 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
Header 2
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

I want to read Header 1 then read line 3 and 4 below it, after that I want to read Header 2 then read line 3 and 4 below it in different context. The string for searching line 3 and 4 in both cases is the same, but lines are not completely same. Presently I am searching for header 1 using

```
for line in file    
    if "Header 1" in line:
```

I am not able to use readline inside for loop of this file to read a block of 4 lines.

Comment: What do you have so far? What is it doing that it shouldn't? Or what part is missing?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by different context.

Comment: The question appears quite similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14742446/989121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all the lines, then analyze them:

```
data = open("filename.txt").readlines()
```

That will make it easy to jump between lines as required, which is not true when reading straight from a file.

Answer (score 0):

unwind's answer is good for small files. If you want a general solution, stick to iterators and generators.

You could define a generator function that yields you tuples of line_i, line_i+3 and line_i+4.

With the imports

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice
```

we can define a new generator-function:

```
def reflexive_zip(iterator, offset = 0):
    offset = int(offset)
    if offset == 0:
        for element in iterator:
            yield (element, element)
    else:
        d = deque(islice(iterator,abs(offset)))
        for element in iterator:
            d.append(element)
            if offset < 0:
                yield (element, d.popleft())
            else:
                yield (d.popleft(), element)
```

It takes an `iterator`, creates some buffer using a `deque` and yields tuples of elements of the `iterator`. Offset can be controlled via the `offset` argument.

Here comes the complete script. Usage example are in the **main** part.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from cStringIO import StringIO

    f = StringIO("""Header 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
Header 2
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4""")

    #for line, other_line in reflexive_zip(f, 4):
    #    print "%s -> %s" %(line, other_line)

    for ((line, _ignore),(line3, line4)) in reflexive_zip(reflexive_zip(f,1),3):
        print "%s -> %s    %s" %(line, line3, line4)


from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

def reflexive_zip(iterator, offset = 0):
    offset = int(offset)
    if offset == 0:
        for element in iterator:
            yield (element, element)
    else:
        d = deque(islice(iterator,abs(offset)))
        for element in iterator:
            d.append(element)
            if offset < 0:
                yield (element, d.popleft())
            else:
                yield (d.popleft(), element)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from cStringIO import StringIO

    f = StringIO("""Header 1
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
Header 2
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4""")

    #for line, other_line in reflexive_zip(f, 4):
    #    print "%s -> %s" %(line, other_line)

    for ((line, _ignore),(line3, line4)) in reflexive_zip(reflexive_zip(f,1),3):
        print "%s -> %s    %s" %(line, line3, line4)
```

Output:

```
Header 1
 -> line 3
    line 4

line 1
 -> line 4
    Header 2

line 2
 -> Header 2
    line 1

line 3
 -> line 1
    line 2

line 4
 -> line 2
    line 3

Header 2
 -> line 3
    line 4
```